# How to "lock" an html radiobutton after selection?

Tags: html, css

Given this checkbox html element:

```html
    <h4>This is a question?</h4>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q">answer 1</input>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q">answer 2</input>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q">answer 3</input>
```

How can I lock the state of a checkbox after it has been selected? That is, how can I avoid the user to change his answer?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, however it would be good to have both solutions if possible @RaulSauco

Comment: What do you mean by "both solutions"? What have you tried? Note that a JavaScript solution can be altered by the user.

Comment: You could utilize the `disabled` HTML attribute and use a JavaScript solution to set the `disabled` property to true after that radio button (or checkbox) was clicked.

Comment: @j08691 with html and javascript is helpful. I am very new with web development.

Comment: @TannerDolby However disabled elements aren't submitted with the form

Comment: Since you using `radiobutton` instead of `checkbox`, Why not give each a distinct name.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Do you mean in the question?

Comment: @anon I've deleted my answer since disabled form fields can't be submitted automatically. Here's the JavaScript code `let elms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[name='q']"));
elms.forEach(elm => elm.addEventListener('change', () => {
  elms.forEach(el => el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'))
}));`

Comment: I meant the name attribute https://jsfiddle.net/rd2pwxLn/

Comment: @j08691 Your correct. I guess one way would to be making the field hidden after click or maybe use `readonly`. I assume the inputs need to be submitted with the form so that makes this tough.

Comment: @ZohirSalak because there is only a single correct answer. It is a way of forcing the user to answer only a single answer

Comment: @TannerDolby Making a hidden input would work. Also, you can't use readonly with radio buttons

Comment: All in all, if you don't use JS to persist the data somehow, users can just reload the page

Comment: @ZohirSalak I see, what about in JS? Teman answer looks pretty good

Comment: Thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hacky idea using CSS. You make a layer that will prevent any click event when one input is checked

```css
.block {
  position:relative;
}

.block input:checked ~ i {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h4>This is a question? (blocked)</h4>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="q1">answer 1
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="q1">answer 2
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="q1">answer 3
  <i></i>
</div>

<div >
  <h4>This is a question? (not blocked)</h4>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="q2">answer 1
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="q2">answer 2
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="q2">answer 3
  <i></i>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks really good, does this has an impact when the user wants to submit the answer? What about if I have more questions and I dont want them to be locked?

Comment: @anon no there is no impact. As you can see I have used a container around the question so only that question will be affect. IF you don't want the other to be, don't add the container

Comment: So this one works for more questions? I just tried it and it seems to work is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    var $inputs = $('input:radio')
        if($(this).is(':radio')){
           $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
        }else{
           $inputs.prop('disabled',false); // <--
        }
    })
```

Try using this.

Refer to the link below http://jsfiddle.net/ur9zxo2e/

Comment: I tried this solution, however I am still able to change my answer after selecting an option. Is this working well?

Comment: Note that disabled elements aren't submitted with the form

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That the values stored in the `<input>` elements will not be submitted with a form due to them having the `disabled` property.

Comment: @anon I have attached the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

With Anush Bhatia's example, you would need to also use JQuery.
Here is a simple snippet without the use of JQuery:

```
    function change(yourname) {
      var radios = document.getElementsByName(youname);
      for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        radios[i].disabled = true;
      }  
    }
```

Remember that you should also call the function on change using

```
<input type="radio" value="1" onchange="change(\"q\");" name="q">answer 1</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make each question be in **ONE** element and apply a `questionHandle` function to each question element

```js
var questionElement1=document.getElementById('q1')

function questionHandle(elem){
  var answered=false
  function listen(ev){
    if(answered){return ev.preventDefault()}
    //else, since this only happens IF not pressed already
    answered=true //so that it will not be pressed again
    //any other thing you want to do for when question is answered below after this INSIDE this function
    console.log(`question ${ev.path[0].value} was chosen`)//an example of anything you can do
  }
  try{
    [...elem.children]
    .forEach(a=>a.addEventListener('click',listen))
  }
  catch(err){return Error(err)}
}

questionHandle(questionElement1)
```

```html
<h4>This is a question?</h4>
  <div id="q1">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="q">answer 1</input>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="q">answer 2</input>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="q">answer 3</input>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do that this way :

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.radioChoice = {}

myForm.oninput = ({target}) =>
  {
  if( target.type === 'radio')
    {
    if (!myForm.radioChoice[target.name])
      myForm.radioChoice[target.name] = target.value
    else
      myForm[target.name].value = myForm.radioChoice[target.name]
    }
  }
```

```html
<form action="" name="my-form">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question 1</legend>

    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="q1" />answer 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="q1" />answer 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="3" name="q1" />answer 3</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question 2</legend>

    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="q2" />answer 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="q2" />answer 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="3" name="q2" />answer 3</label>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```